# Zend Form Validation:: Does exist oposite validator to Identical?[how to check that input not identical to 'str']

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

Zend Form Validation: Is there a validator that is the opposite of Identical (i.e., notIdentical)?
How would I check that an input is not identical to 'str'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is not something like NotIdentical. Have you tried your own validator in that way?:

```
class My_Validate_NotIdentical extends Zend_Validate_Identical
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        return !parent::isValid($value);
    }
}
```

It just simplest solution - you should also change validation messages etc.

Comment: cool! thanks. I don't like zend endless class inheritance that making application very slow, php not compilied language like java/#c - should be also way to do inline validation.Zend not offer this option. example how can inline works: addValidate(true,empty(value)); , but zend not support that option

Comment: Err.. how do we override the validation message?

Comment: Override protected `_messageTemplates` property of `Zend_Validate_Abstract`. But they use constants, so I could be kinda confusing, when message with const `NOT_SAME` gives you 'Strings are the same!' :) In another case, you should override whole `isValid` method (or write validator class by yourself).